# avoid that static number while calculate the sum of column within datagradview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using below code to calculate the sum of a column in `datagridview`
I am afraid about the static number "3" which stand for the index of summarized column  is there anyway to avoid that static number so it will always calculate the sum of same column ?

```
    private double TOTAL_INV()
    {
        double Total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            double num = 0;
            double.TryParse(DGV_INVOICE.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),out num);
            Total+=num;
        }
        return Total;
    }
```

Comment: You can use the column field name as a string or the column attribute generated by by your bindingSource (if you`re using one)

Comment: Is the DataGridView bound to some back-end data source?  Can you get the column index from _that_?

Comment: @VitorRigoni no I am not using datagridview as binding source I am adding record to datagridview then after all process I am inserting data into oracle database

Comment: @DStanley as I said to VitorRigoni  I am adding record to datagridview then after all process I am inserting data into oracle database i think that is better than opening and closing connection and disconnect connection with each modification or transaction that user do... so I think i am not able to get indext with the way you suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column number needs to come from somewhere, be it hard-coded or configured in some other way. What you can do, though, is to make it more visible.

For example, you could make a method that totals *any* column, like this:

```
private double TotalColumn(int col) {
    double Total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DGV_INVOICE.Rows.Count; ++i) {
        double num = 0;
        if (double.TryParse(DGV_INVOICE.Rows[i].Cells[col].Value.ToString(), out num)) {
            Total+=num;
        }
    }
    return Total;
}
```

Now the caller decides what column number to pass to your method. It is a good idea to give it a name, rather than using `3` as an anonymous constant:

```
const int invoiceColumn = 3;
...
var total = TotalColumn(invoiceColumn);
```